# Generic Key Value store with associated type

Tags: swift

I want to design a key/value config store for my application.

I am trying to come up with `ConfigurationStore` protocol that allows me to set and get config values from a central location (can be a map in this case). The values need to be type checked for a particular key. eg: value for `timeInSeconds` cannot be a `String`

```
// psuedocode
protocol ConfigurationStore {

    set(key: TypeCheckedKey, value: AssociatedValueForThatKey)

    get(key: TypeCheckedKey) -> AssociatedValueForThatKey?

}
```

The keys and their associated values need to be type checked. eg. I should not be able to call set for the same key with 2 different value types. There may need to be a mapping of the Key:ValueType pair of some sort.

How would I go about doing it ? I currently want to support `Int`, `Double` and `String` config values

I thought about using enums for keys but then I can set multiple value types to the same key.

All of this needs to be generic so that the keys and values can be defined by the consumer of the application.

Comment: Show an example of how you would use this, even if it doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protocol ConfigurationStore {
    associatedtype TypeCheckedKey
    associatedtype AssociatedValueWithTheKey

    func set(key: TypeCheckedKey, value: AssociatedValueWithTheKey)
    func get(key: TypeCheckedKey) -> AssocicatedValueWithTheyKey?    
}
```

UPD:

```
final class SomeStore: ConfigurationStore {
    typealias TypeCheckedKey = String
    typealias AssociatedValueWithTheKey = String

    func set(key: TypeCheckedKey, value: AssociatedValueWithTheKey) {
        // your realisation
    }
    
    func get(key: TypeCheckedKey) -> AssocicatedValueWithTheyKey? {
        // your realisation
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I map which key belongs to which value type ?

Comment: @user2416162 it should be your realization. protocol describe your interface/abstraction

Comment: How do I make the abstraction generic enough yet it knows what Values type is allowed for a key